# How do I create a multi-column layout based off of AdminLTE that grows with sidebar content?

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I have the following layout which is a alteration of the [AdminLTE boxed layout template](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/layout/boxed.html):

## HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="leftbar">
    Left bar
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="content-rightbar">
      Right bar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222d32;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1030;
  color: white;
  background-color: #367fa9;
  padding: 2px;
}

.leftbar {
  color: white;
  background-color: #222d32;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 810;
  padding: 40px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #ecf0f5;
  z-index: 800;
}

.content {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.content-rightbar {
  right: 0;
  min-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: absolute;
  background: #f9fafc;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  z-index: 1010;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 40px 10px 0 10px;
}

.footer {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  margin-left: 100px;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

## Codepen

https://codepen.io/kspearrin/pen/QqBrpB

## Result

[image]

## Problems

This looks precisely how I would like it to with one problem:

- Overflowing the `leftbar` and `content-rightbar` with content causes the overflowed content to be hidden. Height is only determined by the content inside `content`.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

## Question

How can I make it so that the either the entire layout's height within the `body` increases with the content of the `content`, `leftbar`, and `content-rightbar` - OR - that the `leftbar` and `content-rightbar` scroll with their overflowing content?

Comment: I highly suggest to try something like Bootstrap and some other JS libraries.

Comment: This uses bootstrap.

Comment: Try setting up your layout using Bootstrap Grid. Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/ And a used to love a little library called Nicescroll. Here is an example of the library https://jsfiddle.net/inuyaksa/thohu1se/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your overflow to hidden for your wrapper, you can just set it to "auto" or "scroll" to show the content inside your container. Only then it will take it will be longer then your content container and then it will take in the whole width because there are no other elements right there.

I would in fact recommend you to reconsider using flex box as it will keep your elements at the same height and will prevent all the overflow issues you have right now.

If you are unfamiliar with flex boxes I can recommend you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ at the end you will find an example for a multi column layout which includes all the elements you need for your project.

Also another tip: You could use an unordered list for your sidebar items, as this is the most common way to do it.

```css
ul {list-style: none;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Left bar</li>
    <li>Left bar</li>
    <li>Left bar</li>
</ul>
```